# How can I attach a bluetooth module to a Netduino?

Tags: installation, bluetooth

I have a [netduino](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10107) and I just bought an [RN-42 Bluetooth module](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10253). There are no actual pins on the module, so I'm wondering if there's a special attachment that I need, or some other method of attaching this module to a netduino.

Here's the module
[image]

Here's the netduino
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably have better luck getting the version of the module that's mounted to a breakout board:

[image: front]

[image: back]

More info on using it is available on this blog: [Netduino and Bluetooth (RN-42)](http://blog.mark-stevens.co.uk/?p=180), as well as a few others.

Comment: This makes perfect sense, however, is there a breakout board available separate? since I already have the module?

Comment: I doubt it, as you'd probably need specialized soldering equipment to cleanly surface-mount the module onto the breakout board.  You're probably better off asking Sparkfun about availability though. ;)

Comment: yeah, that's what I'm thinking. I have micro soldering equipment at work, but it might be a bit of a chore.